# Sending a Tweet with Corona SDK

Tags: twitter, sdk, coronasdk

i'm trying to send a tweet to a twitter account with a preset username and password, using the windows simulator so i can't use any native features.

I also tried following http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/twitter but it appears that the method this uses might be outdated and doesn't work.

Any replies appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter changed their service to redirect http calls to https a couple of months ago.  The sample code uses a new updated oAuth.lua file that now handles the https properly.  If you look at the sample code and use the latest oAuth.lua library you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Look into samples that come with Corona SDK, there is one with twitter.
Or grab my version of the lib (cleaner code) here http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/twitter-fix-https